# convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss to yyyy-mm-dd in sql

Tags: sql, t-sql, date, datetime, converters

I need to convert yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.msec to yyyy-mm-dd in sql.

I tried

```
CONVERT(DATETIME,MIN(Vdaily_calender.VDC_day_date),120)
```

but getting same result.

Please advise

Thanks
    Ar

Comment: Tip: When you ask database questions, tag the question with the database software you are using, e.g. `sql-server-2014`, and specify the data types of the values involved. Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some additional tips.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I suspect you are overthinking it.  A simple cast as date will do the trick

```
Select Cast(SomeDateTime as date)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
CAST(MyDateTimeField AS Date) AS MyDateField
```

Answer (score 2):

Select Cast(SomeDate as datetime)

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you need the date without the time, then a convert or cast to a date will do.

```
CONVERT(DATE,MIN(Vdaily_calender.VDC_day_date),20)
```

An example showing [convert](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp), cast, format:

```
declare @mydatetime datetime = '2016-10-17 15:30:45.123';

select
@mydatetime as MyDateTime, 
convert(date,@mydatetime) as ConvertedToDate,
convert(varchar(10),@mydatetime,21) as ConvertedToDateString,
cast(@mydatetime as date) as CastedAsDate,
cast(cast(@mydatetime as date) as varchar) CastedAsDateString,
format(@mydatetime,'yyyy-MM-dd') as FormattedToDateString; -- SQL Server 2012 or higher
```

Answer (score 1):

**convertion from yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.msec to yyyy-mm-dd in sql:**

```
   SELECT convert(date,GETDATE(), 120)
```

**result:**

[image: image1]

Comment: could you explain to me why that parameter 120?